# How to prevent calendar items from appearing in conversation view threads in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I noticed that in a certain e-mail thread where the subject matched the name of several calendar items, the calendar items also appear in the thread. That's totally useless to me, because I use my calendar to plan my day-to-day work, so these items don't add value. And either way, they are NOT part of the conversation thread.

I see that including items from other folders in threads is an on/off option with no possibility to exclude folders or item-types. I want to include items from other folders mainly to include sent items in the threads, but I don't want calendar items in my threads.

Is that possible?

Edit:
As far as I know there is no built-in setting to achieve this, but perhaps there's a registry key that might control how items of a particula type (in this case calendar items) partake in the conversation view?

Comment: I have this same question - I need the "show message from other folders" to be on, but I don't want to see the calendar items ... because, then if I archive the thread, Outlook archives the calendar item as well - painful...

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Outlook 2010, but from the documentation I wonder if a possible solution is to go to the View tab, in the Arrangement group, and click Conversations, then turn off `Show Messages from Other Folders`.

[image: image1]

I am afraid this is an "all or nothing" setting. I haven't managed to find any way of selectively specifying from which folders to show messages. The only two options seem to be All Folders or Current Folder :

[image: image2]

Comment: No, because then threading becomes more or less pointless, because you don't see sent messages or messages that are no longer in the inbox in the same thread.

Comment: Just for information: Does this setting avoid the problem?

Comment: This setting does not avoid the problem because now  conversations don't include sent items. You'd need to drag each sent message into the same folder to see the conversation as a whole.

Comment: See my above edit.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to turn off "Show messages from other folders".  Then create a custom search folder that only looks at the folders you wish to see in the conversation (in my case sent items and inbox), then if conversation view is on it will span the folders you have checked in the search.  I think that might be what you are trying to do.  The only limitation is which folders a saved search will or will not cover.